# how do I set cookie expiration time in user local time?

Tags: c#, cookies

I want a cookie to expire in 10 minutes precisely (just for the sake of argument).

If I use `Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)` and user is 3 hours behind me, cookie will expire as soon as it is received (is this correct?)

How do I set expiration so it is local to user?

Sure, I can use JavaScript to send that info together with the request, or use a JS-library of some sort to create cookie on the client side, or keep user profile and ask user for time zone, but I am looking a lazy-man solution.

Comment: a relevant thread: http://techpatterns.com/forums/about849.html

Comment: Seems like Set-Cookie `expires` field format is `Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT` which renders my question faulty. Cookie expiration is not local-time specific, it is GMT.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cookie expiration date will end up as a GMT time, so your code will simply work.

Comment: see my comment to the question. Cookies' expiration time is given in GMT, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user93422 - See my updated answer. Looks like you _can_ set the cookie to a _local_ server time.

Comment: even if you use `DateTime.Now` it will translate it to UTC using current (server) time zone. So any way you do it - you get correct expiration. Magic happens here: `dt = dt.ToUniversalTime();` - which will adjust the time if its not UTC. (`HttpUtility::FormatHttpCookieDateTime`)

Comment: "If the DateTimeKind property is set to Unspecified, then Utc is assumed" - I believe DateTime.Kind.Unspecified is assumed to be local.